# Get the value of unchecked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the vaule of the unchecked boxes

**HTML:**

```
<br> 
<input class="computer_type" id="laptop" type="checkbox" checked> Laptops
<br>
<input class="computer_type" id="desktop" type="checkbox" checked> Desktops
```

**javascript:**

```
function get_computer_type() {
    $('.computer_type:not(:checked)').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('id');
    }).get();

}

$('.computer_type').change(function() {
    console.log(get_computer_type());
});
```

Unfortunately, this returns undefined and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Because `get_computer_type()` doesn't return anything: `return $('.computer_type:not(:checked)').map(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is not returning anything, thus returns *undefined* (In JavaScript, if function does not return anything explicitly, by default it returns *undefined*). You have to *return* the result getting from `map()` from the function.

```js
function get_computer_type() {
  return $('.computer_type:not(:checked)').map(function() {
     return $(this).attr('id');
  }).get(); 
}

$('.computer_type').change(function(){
 console.log(get_computer_type());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br> 
<input class="computer_type" id="laptop" type="checkbox" checked> Laptops
<br>
<input class="computer_type" id="desktop" type="checkbox" checked> Desktops
```